# SwitchPreferenceCompat setOnPreferenceChangeListener crashes app

Tags: java, android-preferences, android-settings

My application crash when I go to my settings activity and the error is

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> androidx.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(androidx.preference.Preference$OnPreferenceChangeListener)'
> on a null object reference
> at com.may.restroomv2.SettingsActivity_2$SettingsFragment.onCreatePreferences(SettingsActivity_2.java:77)

My code is

**XML**

```
<PreferenceCategory app:title="Dark Mode">

   <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:summaryOff="Not active"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        app:summaryOn="Active"
        app:key="@string/darkmode"
        app:title="Dark Mode" />
    
</PreferenceCategory>
```

**SettingsFragment**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
SwitchPreferenceCompat switch_darkmode = (SwitchPreferenceCompat) findPreference("@string/darkmode");

switch_darkmode.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        if (switch_darkmode.isChecked()) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            // bottomNavigationView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_nav_darkmode);
        } else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            // bottomNavigationView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_nav);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SwitchPreferenceCompat switch_darkmode = (SwitchPreferenceCompat) findPreference(
    getResources().getString(R.string.darkmode)
);
```

### Explanation

[`findPreference(CharSequence key)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)) get the argument as a `CharSequence`. If you put `"@string/darkmode"`, it get this string literally as the key. That is why your `findPreference` failed to find `switch_darkmode` then end up with `NullPointerException`. Only when you use this kind of expression in XML files (layout, menu or preference, etc.), it is translated to corresponding resource value at build-time by Android Studio.